# custom cell not being displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode5

So i created a custom cell (using the .xib file) and linked it using a custom controller class and I also didn't forget to write in the cell identifier. I also gave the same cell identifier in my table view controller prototype cell. In the custom cell controller class I just have an outlet to a text label in the .h file. Below is the code for my table view controller. When I run the app, the custom cells are not displayed but there are cells there because i can click on them (but they are just white). What am I doing wrong, why aren't the custom cells displaying?

If I use the default cells (not custom), then everything works fine. So the problem is that I'm not using my custom cells correctly somewhere.

```
#import "ListmaniaTableViewController.h"
#import "ListmaniaTableViewCell.h"

@interface ListmaniaTableViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tasks; //of task object

@end

@implementation ListmaniaTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    task *task1 = [[task alloc] init];
    task1.taskDescription = @"TASK 1";
    [self.tasks addObject:task1];
    task *task2 = [[task alloc] init];
    task2.taskDescription = @"TASK 2";
    [self.tasks addObject:task2];
    task *task3 = [[task alloc] init];
    task3.taskDescription = @"TASK 3";
    [self.tasks addObject:task3];
}

- (NSMutableArray *)tasks{
    if(!_tasks){
        _tasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return _tasks;
}

/*- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;

}*/

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Add New Item"]) {

    }
}

- (void)addNewTask:(task *)newTask{
    [self.tasks addObject:newTask];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.tasks count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ListmaniaTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListmaniaCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(!cell){
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ListmaniaTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ListmaniaCell"];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListmaniaCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(ListmaniaTableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   {
    task *task = [self.tasks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *taskLabel = task.taskDescription;
    cell.taskLabel.text = taskLabel;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

But the

```
        [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ListmaniaTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ListmaniaCell"];
```

in `viewDidLoad:`.

Comment: When I do, the app crashes on startup and the console says "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Comment: I did use self.tableView when it crashed

Comment: What does the crash log states?

Comment: same thing "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Answer (score 0):

The code you have in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method should be in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ListmaniaTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListmaniaCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(!cell){
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ListmaniaTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ListmaniaCell"];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListmaniaCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    task *task = [self.tasks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *taskLabel = task.taskDescription;
    cell.taskLabel.text = taskLabel;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: that wouldn't change anything (I just tried it again and no change)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I had an outlet in the custom cell that was doubly linked. I also moved the line below into viewdidload as suggested by @dasdom

```
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ListmaniaTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ListmaniaCell"];
```